# Why do fully qualified names have to be used when dynamically assessing namespaced elements?

Tags: php, namespaces, php-7

I have been trying to understand the chapter [Namespaces and dynamic language features](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.dynamic.php) from php.net manual. Please consider the following code:

```
namespace Foo;

function strstr() {
    echo "My local ststr method called";
}

$a = 'strstr';
$a(); //This would call the global strstr method
```

As per the manual, I have to go `$a = 'Foo\strstr'`, but I can't find a reason for this. Why can't php interpreter at runtime know that `$a = 'strstr';` was defined in the context of `namespace Foo`, just like executing `strstr()` straightaway the interpreter remember the context is `namespace Foo` at runtime.

One reason I can think of is `$a` to be called on an event if a certain condition(like if user input received) is met, because then the function is just bound to the event without any contextual information.

Comment: And if you write `$a = 'Foo\strstr';` php should understand it how?

Comment: @u_mulder It converts it to `$a = '\Foo\strstr';`. At runtime it just substitutes the value of `$a` before `()`. This is what I understand; I might be wrong.

Comment: I mean: you would prefer that php __would understand__ that in `$a = 'strstr'` you mean `Foo\strstr`. So when you write `$a = 'Foo\strstr'`, according to your logic php __would understand__ that you mean `Foo\Foo\strstr`? Or remove `Foo` as already in Foo namesapce? Don't you think that this is rather complicated?

Comment: Probably because when you call a function its "path" (namespace) evaluates at compile time (pass #1), so it automatically prepends the namespace of the file you're in. While in your sample, it's evaluated during runtime, and the notion of "source file" per se doesn't exist anymore. In any case, you can use `$a = __NAMESPACE__ . '\\strstr';`.

Comment: @u_mulder Actually I would prefer the later, **because** that's how php operate on `strstr()` direct call. It takes it as `\Foo\strstr()` and it takes `Foo\strstr()` as `\Foo\Foo\strstr()`. It would have made things easier to remember if both ways php acted the same.

Comment: Add
use strstr; after the namespace declaration.

Comment: Question is not about `use`.

Answer (score 2):

More from [PHP docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php#example-262) on imports:

> Importing is performed at compile-time, and so does not affect dynamic class, function or constant names.

I couldn't find the reason for this decision, but I'd imagine it is a combination of the following:

1. Performance - resolving imports for dynamic names on each use could be costly. This can't be done during compilation due to the dynamic nature of PHP and its strings.
2. Consistency and avoiding complexity - for dynamic names to work the way you describe, several issues would have to be resolved, like passing them to different scripts with different imports, serialization/deserialization etc.

It seems to me that treating all dynamic names as fully-qualified was the easiest solution. I also can't imagine a real-world use-case since most code can do without using dynamic names like that at all.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on #1.

Comment: Dynamic names can't be resolved during compile time, so they'd to be resolved on each use. I'm not saying it could not be optimized/cached somehow, just that it'd likely be slower than just using fully-qualified names.

Answer (score 2):

Let's inspect the opcodes that are generated (using `php -d opcache.opt_debug_level=0x10000 test.php`):

The code:

```
<?php

namespace Foo;

function strstr() {
    echo "My local ststr method called";
}

$a = 'strstr';
$a();

strstr();
```

The opcodes:

```
$_main: ; (lines=7, args=0, vars=1, tmps=3)
    ; (before optimizer)
    ; /code/test.php:1-13
L0 (5):     NOP
L1 (9):     ASSIGN CV0($a) string("strstr")
L2 (10):    INIT_DYNAMIC_CALL 0 CV0($a)
L3 (10):    DO_FCALL
L4 (12):    INIT_NS_FCALL_BY_NAME 0 string("Foo\strstr")
L5 (12):    DO_FCALL
L6 (13):    RETURN int(1)

Foo\strstr: ; (lines=2, args=0, vars=0, tmps=0)
    ; (before optimizer)
    ; /code/test.php:5-7
L0 (6):     ECHO string("My local ststr method called")
L1 (7):     RETURN null
```

As you can see `$a()` is using the `INIT_DYNAMIC_CALL` opcode. When the passed function name is a string, it is treated as being fully qualified.

On the other hand `strstr()` uses the `INIT_NS_FCALL_BY_NAME` opcode, with the name resolved in the current namespace passed to it. Upon execution it will first look for that name (`Foo\strstr`), and when that does not exist it will fall back to the global namespace.

Answer (score 1):

The main reason is probably that it would make the result completely unpredictable. Value of variable can be passed as argument to another function/method in different namespace, which could pass it further to different namespace. If this value will be treated as relative name, it will mean completely different things depending on context. Take [this example](https://3v4l.org/PgZMi):

```
namespace A {
    function test() {
        echo __FUNCTION__, "\n";
    }

    function run($callback) {
        $callback();
    }
}


namespace B {
    function test() {
        echo __FUNCTION__, "\n";
    }

    function run($callback) {
        $callback();
    }
}

namespace {
    function test() {
        echo __FUNCTION__, "\n";
    }

    function run($callback) {
        $callback();
    }

    $callback = 'test';
    run($callback);
    A\run($callback);
    B\run($callback);

    $callback = 'A\test';
    run($callback);
    A\run($callback);
    B\run($callback);
}
```

Now callback is treated always in the same consistent way:

```
test
test
test
A\test
A\test
A\test
```

If you would interpret dynamic callback as relative name, you will get pure madness, where each call will give you different result:

```
test
A\test
B\test
A\test
A\A\test
B\A\test
```

Treating strings as FQN makes it much simpler and more predictable.

Comment: `+1` for _You will get pure madness_. I had to keep thinking for around 20 mins with your code in front of me to see who is calling who with relative names taken for dynamic callbacks. But if you call say `B\run('A\test')`, isn't it the same level of obfuscation, I mean even without the dynamic function calls, its still madness.

Comment: I have a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60576442/3429430), would you be able to explain that as well.

Comment: @user31782 It is pretty straightforward for me, since `'A\test'` always means the same thing and points to the same `A\test()` function. I don't really understand your second question.